# Problems using TPT (Table Per Type) in EF 4.2 and deletion of parent objects

Tags: entity-framework

From what I understand on several posts the TPT architecure, with EF, does not create the necessary ON DELETE CASCADE when using a shared primary key.... It was also said that the EF context will handle the proper order of deletion of the sub-classed tables (however I do get an error that it breaks the constraint and that I can fix it with adding the ON DELETE CASCADE on the sub-class table)...

more background info...

I have a Section class, which has a number, title, and a list of pages. The page is designed using a super class which holds basic page properties. I have about 10+ sub-classes of the page class. The Section class holds an ICollection of these pages. The DB is created properly with the exception of no ON DELETE CASCADE on the sub-classed tables.

My code will create the entities and adds to the DB fine. However, if I try to delete a section (or all sections) it fails todelete due to the FK constraint on my sub-class page table...

```
public abstract BaseContent 
{
... common properties which are Ignored in the DB ...
}

public class Course : BaseContent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Descripiton {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters{get;set;}
    ...
}

public class Chapter : BaseContent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Number {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public virtual Course MyCourse{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections{get;set;}
    ...
}

public class Section : BaseContent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Number {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public virtual Chapter MyChapter {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<BasePage> Pages {get;set;}
    ...
}

public abstract class BasePage : BaseContent, IComparable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PageImageRef { get; set; }
    public ePageImageLocation ImageLocationOnPage { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Section MySection { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ChapterPage : BasePage
{
    public virtual int ChapterNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChapterTitle  { get; set; }
    public virtual string AudioRef { get; set; }
}

public class SectionPage : BasePage
{
    public virtual int SectionNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string SectionTitle  { get; set; }
    public virtual string SectionIntroduction { get; set; }
}
```

... plus about 8 other BasePage sub-classes...

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
...
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BasePage> Pages { get; set; }
...
}
```

.. Fluent API ... (note Schema is defined to "" for SqlServer, for Oracle its the schema name)

```
private EntityTypeConfiguration<T> configureTablePerType<T>(string tableName) where T : BaseContent
{
    var config = new EntityTypeConfiguration<T>();

    config.ToTable(tableName, Schema);

    // This adds the appropriate Ignore calls on config for the base class BaseContent
    DataAccessUtilityClass.IgnoreAllBaseContentProperties<T>(config);

    return config;
}

public virtual EntityTypeConfiguration<BasePage> ConfigurePageContent()
{
    var config = configureTablePerType<BasePage>("PageContent");

    config.HasKey(pg => pg.Id);
    config.HasRequired(pg => pg.Title);
    config.HasOptional(pg => pg.PageImageRef);

    config.Ignore(pg => pg.ImageLocationOnPage);

    return config;
}

public virtual EntityTypeConfiguration<ChapterPage> ConfigureChapterPage()
{
    var config = configureTablePerType<ChapterPage>("ChapterPage");

    config.HasOptional(pg => pg.AudioRef);
    config.Ignore(pg => pg.ChapterNumber);
    config.Ignore(pg => pg.ChapterTitle);

    return config;
}

public virtual EntityTypeConfiguration<SectionPage> ConfigureSectionPage()
{
    var config = configureTablePerType<SectionPage>("SectionPage");

    config.HasOptional(pg => pg.AudioRef);
    config.Ignore(pg => pg.SectionNumber);
    config.Ignore(pg => pg.SectionTitle);

    return config;
}
```

... other code to model other tables...

So the app is able to populate content and the relationships are properly set up. However, when I try to delete the course, I get the error that the delete failed due to the constraint on the ChapterPage to PageContent table..

Here is the code which deletes the Course (actually I delete all courses)...

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    ctx.Courses.ToList().ForEach(crs => ctx.Courses.Remove(crs));
    AttachLookupEntities(ctx);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I add the 'ON DELETE CASCADE' in the ChapterPage and SectionPage table for its shared primary with PageContent, the delete goes through.

In summary,

The only solution that I have seen is to manually alter the constraints to add the ON DELETE CASCADE for all of my sub-class page tables. I can implement the change, as I have code which generates the DB script for the EF tables I need (a small subset of our whole DB) since we will not use EF to create or instantiate the DB (since it does not properly support migrations as yet...).

I sincerely hope that I have miscoded something, or forgot some setting in the model builder logic. Because if not, the EF designers have defined an architecure (TPT design approach) which cannot be used in any real world situation without a hack workaround. It's a half finished solution. Do not get me wrong, I like the work that has been done, and like most MSFT solutions its works for 70% of most basic application usages. It just is not ready for more complex situations.

I was trying to keep the DB design all within the EF fluent API and self-contained. It's about 98% there for me, just would be nice if they finished the job, maybe in the next release. At least it saves me all the CRUD operations.

Ciao!
Jim Shaw

Comment: Is there a cascading delete for `Course.Chapters`, `Chapter.Sections` and `Section.Pages` and are these one-to-many relationships required or optional? For me this looks as if one has to load the BasePages into the context and then delete them explicitely and EF creates then two DELETE statements (for base and derived table). If deleting relies on a chain of cascading deletes of other entities the DB is responsible to delete every related objects with proper cascading deletes which EF apparently doesn't create. I'd call this a bug or at least some kind of hidden limitation one has to aware of.

Comment: Yes there is. I tried to have the context use the Include pages logic, but it still fails. I have decided to go with the Add constraints solution, as we will/cannot use the EF dynamic DB creation logic as it's not incremental (maybe when the migrations project is finished). I have been writing a script generator utility to use the context write db script and some auto generated cascade delete scripts to augment the db script). We will be using a separate .sql file to model the DB...

Answer (score 5):

I have reproduced the problem with a little bit simpler example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EFTPT
{
    public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BasePage> Pages { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BasePage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedPage : BasePage
    {
        public string DerivedName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BasePage> BasePages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Pages)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Parent);  // creates casc. delete in DB

            modelBuilder.Entity<BasePage>()
                .ToTable("BasePages");

            modelBuilder.Entity<DerivedPage>()
                .ToTable("DerivedPages");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                var parent = new Parent { Pages = new List<BasePage>() };
                var derivedPage = new DerivedPage();

                parent.Pages.Add(derivedPage);

                ctx.Parents.Add(parent);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                var parent = ctx.Parents.FirstOrDefault();
                ctx.Parents.Remove(parent);
                ctx.SaveChanges();  // exception here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the same exception that you had too. Only solutions seem to be:

- Either setup cascading delete for the TPT constraint in the DB manually, as you already tested (or put an appropriate SQL command into the `Seed` method).
- Or load the entites which are involved in the TPT inheritance into memory. In my example code:

  ```
  var parent = ctx.Parents.Include(p => p.Pages).FirstOrDefault();
  ```

  When the entities are loaded into the context, EF creates actually two DELETE statements - one for the base table and one for the derived table. In your case, this is a terrible solution because you had to load a much more complex object graph before you can get the TPT entities.

Even more problematic is if `Parent` has an `ICollection<DerivedPage>` (and the inverse `Parent` property is in `DerivedPage` then):

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DerivedPage> Pages { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BasePage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedPage : BasePage
{
    public string DerivedName { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The example code wouldn't throw an exception but instead delete the row from the derived table but **not** from the base table, leaving a phantom row which cannot represent an entity anymore because `BasePage` is abstract. This problem is not solvable by a cascading delete but you were actually forced to load the collection into the context before you can delete the parent to avoid such a nonsense in the database.

A similar question and analysis was here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3c27d761-4d0a-4704-85f3-8566fa37d14e/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I decided to use the scripts and auto/hand-cranked constraint script for db creation. This way I can still use EF for CRUD operations in our application (and they are rather simple, delete course, delete chapter... and DB handles appropriately.

Comment: It's solvable with a trigger though and really entity framework should either handle this or put a big warning on such features.